# Looking for a place

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cipher, geography, computer-puzzle

***Seems overwhelming but pretty simple.***

**clue.txt**
http://junewi.000webhostapp.com/testing/clue.txt

tdHCR6ieFHNqUv1zQHE0KRiAfypNTApKi2xlN4CMYK2beP3M1u2mgUvRvDmx0M8heyKebUVEsGcbHrnymUIeviUN/oG4WYzMe5AzvHPzrSEr96M4XM6T8b7vHVv9CUiO+UlEkhOSER6ahH3t62CCH6/1WkrBNUuLmqW7hrDZYB7TA0m0rf9ydUQvrSyEqmUYW5ZpDzPsxFkwQ0hBgWaXpaQ457L0n7w7IvYgPDxibmD2g7w5iw3+fVcS

HINT:

> https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/
>  
>  Also, for the hebrew word; I'm looking for the transliteration of it.
>  
>   *i.e: צוּר is rock but transliteration is tsur*

Comment: This looks a lot like phishing emails that I've received, ha ha, ha ha. I'm sure this puzzle is great though.

Comment: In my humble opinion, instead of using the `riddle` tag, I guess the `enigmatic-puzzle` tag would be more appropriate? Again, that is just my opinion, so I don't mind if you agree or disagree.

Comment: ahaha no worries, there`s more to the puzzle that makes it a riddle!

Comment: @jwi this was a good puzzle! Are you from the area (where I hope my solution is correct) too? :D

Comment: yep gotta represent Toronto!

Comment: Sweet! Welcome to Puzzling.SE, from a fellow GTAer! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, building on @Bennett Bernardoni and @Hugh's answers, that the name of the place you are looking for is

> TORONTO (shout-out to Canada! :D)

This is because

> Near the water, but on land. 
>  **Toronto is on [Lake Ontario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Ontario), but is on the land** 
>  Has an island, but not on that. 
>  **This refers to [Toronto Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Islands)** 
>  A city of six, and four things surrounding that. 
>  **This refers to the fact that Toronto is referred to as [The 6ix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six) because of the [amalgamation of Toronto's six neighbourhoods](https://www.thestar.com/news/gta/2017/01/01/19-years-ago-torontos-six-boroughs-amalgamated.html); and is surrounded by [4 municipalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_in_the_Greater_Toronto_Area) (Shout-out to Durham Region!)** 
>  In a place of nice people, 
>  **Canada is [a friendly place!](https://globalnews.ca/news/3492809/canada-150-what-travellers-have-to-say-about-canadians/)** 
>  where the jays sing. 
>  **[OK! Blue Jays! Let's! Play! Ball!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Blue_Jays)** 
>  But dinosaurs roam the land. 
>  **[Welcome to Jurassic Park! We the North!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Raptors)**

Comment: Yup, I think you've got it. Six = six neighborhoods merged during the Amalgamation of Toronto, four = four surrounding cities (York, Durham, Peel, Halton), jays = Blue Jays, dinosaur = dinosaur museum?

Comment: I think I've got my full explanation there now! You're a little off for the dinosaurs, but otherwise yes! @Hugh

Comment: Hehe. The rest of my family's from Toronto... I'm the only one on the other side of the country.

Comment: It gets all the love, I've seen a few puzzles discussing this side of the country but not too much about out west!

Comment: Its correct! Thank you everyone for contributing

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer so far.

> I downloaded the linked file and converted it to a jpeg like the mime type suggests and got this image.
>  [image: decoded image]
>
>  From here, there is several things to work with.
>
>  The first thing that stuck out was the non-english word. The language looked familiar but I couldn't initially place it. After a quick search I found that it is hebrew. So, with the help of google translate, we find that the word is [God](https://translate.google.com/#iw/en/%D7%90%D6%B1%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%A7%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D).
>
>  Next the five number code and Georgia. This immediately appears to be a zip code and looking it up it's the zip code for Enigma, Georgia. This probably is referencing an [Enigma Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine).
>
>  Finally, we have the word stream and a picture of a key. This reminds me of a [Stream Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher), which uses some cryptographic key. Furthermore, I believe the Enigma Machine uses a type of Stream Cipher.
>
>  Since the car is going away from Enigma and towards god, I figure that god is probably the key and the base64 text in the question is the cipher text. But this is where I am stuck. I don't know what stream cipher to use. I tried RC4 with the key as `god`, `God`, and `GOD`, but no such luck.

Comment: On the right track! But look more in to the cipher method and the key!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer, building from Bennett Bernardoni...

> Using the hint provided, if we decrypt the text in the puzzle using the "enigma" algorithm using "STREAM" mode with the key "elohim" (the transliteration of "אֱלֹהִים"), we obtain the following poem: 
>  *Near the water, but on land.* 
>  *Has an island, but not on that.* 
>  *A city of six, and four things surrounding that.* 
>  *In a place of nice people,* 
>  *where the jays sing.* 
>  *But dinosaurs roam the land.*